# A new activity from Android Studio shows an errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-theme

As you'll understand I am new at programming. Well on Android Studio 3.1 when I create a new log in activity it sows me the following error messages:

-Render problem

Couldn't resolve resource `@string/path_password_strike_through`

- Can't morph from `@string/path_password_eye_mask_stike_throught` to `@string/path_password_eye_mask_visible`

Failed to parse file

> C:\Users\summer.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.1.aar\6ef7c3e4dd15f8f070c9e580e709f227\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml

-Render problem

tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

- Can't morph from `@string/path_password_eye_mask_stike_throught` to `@string/path_password_eye_mask_visible`

> Failed to parse file C:\Users\summer.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.1.aar\6ef7c3e4dd15f8f070c9e580e709f227\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml (Details)   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Answer (score 0):

a `drawable` and a `string` resource is something very else - despite both might be `xml`.

that's why it complains: `tag requires a 'drawable' attribute` (and you pass a  `'string'`).

see the documentation to learn about the [available resource types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources).